# Is my wallet really valid?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I am really new to this world so please apologies if that's a stupid question.
I have generated my monero wallet with this tool: https://moneroaddress.org/
And kept al the information somewhere in a file I encrypted.
I have started using [xmr-stack](https://github.com/psychocrypt/xmr-stak) to "mine".
When I started xmr-stack it asked me for the pool address (I'm mining on monerohash) and my wallet I wanted to use. things seems to be working (at least I can see no errors) but to be very honest, I have no idea what I'm really doing here.
From What I read I can check my wallet using monero-wallet-cli. So I installed and sync'd monerod and then tried to use the wallet cli. but It seems it's willing to created a new wallet.

Can I import the wallet I created before? If yes, then how?
Am I doing anything stupid here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run:

`monero-wallet-cli --restore-deterministic-wallet`

You will be asked for the seed you created earlier.

You will need a running daemon (monerod), which may be one of the public ones or your own, in order to download the blocks to see your transactions. When asked for a refresh height or date, make sure you put one that's when you created your wallet originally.

Comment: Thank you it seems that worked. However my balance is still at 0: Balance: 0.000000000000, unlocked balance: 0.000000000000
is it normal after a few days of mining (even though I have a terrible hash rate ~ 50 H/s)?

Comment: If you're solo mining, it's normal, it's a lottery for all intents and purposes. If pool mining, that's probaly normal, most pay out when your dues reach half a monero (you can check your pending balance on the pool using your address).